# Custom shell script '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' No such file or directory for framework

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, xcode8, firebase-cloud-messaging

[image: Screenshot of the error]

I am trying to use Firebase for notifications. And I followed all the steps to install the cocoapods and write the code and get the certificates.And yes I am using xcworkspace to run the program.

Now I am getting this error when I try to run the program. I have exhausted all the suggested solutions on Stack Overflow, from deleting the derived data to restarting xcode and even checking that the $1 has single quotes instead of double quotes as suggested by another answer.

My project name has an 'apostrophe' in its name. So I think that might be the problem. If yes, how do I solve it?

Also when we look closely at the error in the path, we can see that it says tabber.WhatsPoppin.app without the apostrophe. So I think that may be a possible cause of the problem. How do i change the path/rename the file if that is the problem?

There may be something else which might be cause the error. Feel free to suggest anything. I really need the help.

Answer (score 2):

The fix is to get rid of the apostrophe in the directory name for your project. You can keep the apostrophe in the display name of the app, but everywhere else you should get rid of it.

Comment: Is there a safe way to do it? Because I tried doing it once and it just messed up everything.

Comment: The safe way would be to leave your current project as is, create a new one with no apostrophe and then copy/paste the code back in.